# How to refresh the content inside the itemview in RecycleView after adding it in view

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, recyclerview-layout, expandablerecyclerview

Initially it takes full width of screen. But after adding another column. Card size changes but content inside the view is not aligned based on that. Some of the contents are cropped.

Comment: can you provide the sample code? it worths for problem solution.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to provide the sample code. I need to refresh the content inside the card based on card size. Is there is any way to call OnCreateViewHolder for all the columns or refresh the whole columns?

Comment: i'ts upto you. create a referance for that data model and make changes into it and then redraw the view

Comment: Is there is any way to call OnCreateViewHolder for first added column without making any change in models?

Comment: No, Modify the Model data and then inform the recycler view by the notifyDataSetChanged() method. RecyclerView will Redraw itself.